# how to insert into oledb destination from oledb command

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, oledbcommand

I'm trying to insert in a ole db destination the result of a sp for each record in an ole db source,

the sp returns a record set

I have found this  [how to call a stored procedure in SSIS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/ee686cf8-0880-4a1d-8706-ba72fbb2eba8/?ffpr=0#page:1)

but i still can't see the outpout columns in OleDb Command Output Columns

here is my sp:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData] (
    @user        varchar(50)
) AS
set nocount on
-- Publish metadata for ssis
if 1=0
begin
    select '' x, '' y, '' z
end

declare @user_tmp table
(
    x varchar(max),
    y varchar(max),
    z varchar(max)
)

insert into @user_tmp
    select 'x1' x, 'y1' y, 'z1' z

select distinct *  from @user_tmp
set nocount off
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it maybe getting the result of the insert statement?  Try SET NOCOUNT ON.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried table variables, but I know that SSIS will not recognize fields if you  use temp tables and table variables may have the same limitation. It will recognize the fields if you use a CTE however. If you can convert to using a CTE, your proc might work.

Answer (score 0):

- Do use a ***OLE DB Source*** for taking the output of a stored procedure in your data flow.
- Do not use a ***OLE DB Command*** as a source.
- Do use a ***OLE DB Destination*** for the destination of the output of your OLE DB Source (Which gets the SP result data).
- Add in ETL design choices or requirements (Derived columns, Data Conversion, etc) between source and destination.

***OLE DB Command*** is used to perform a SQL for each passing row, not to create a flow of data, for example you need a row-by-row type execution.